# Decompile a DyLib (Dynamic Library)

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering, decompiling, macos, dylib

My question is simple. Is there any way to decompile, reverse engineering of DYLIB files (Dynamic libraries of MAC, like Windows DLL).?

What programs are recommended to do so?
I'm looking some program like Olly or IDA but for MAC.

Thanx in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDA Pro have Mac version, but i don't know is there any free version for Mac
you can use windows version of this software and reverse your Mac library

Comment: FYI, the free version for Windows cannot work with Mac files. And you can certainly use `wine` to run IDA in Mac too. OllyDbg, however, wouldn't work for obvious reason.

Comment: @Nam Nguyen: you can buy expensive IDA (or find it elsewhere) :), or you can use gdb, see this [link](http://reverse.put.as/) maybe help

Comment: I really thank  @Arash #Arash for its link. I was looking for some reading like this one. Believe me in Google, this link doesn't appear.

Comment: Use Ghidra. it is open source and free. https://ghidra-sre.org

Answer (score 1):

[IDA Pro](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/) is available for OS X since version 6.0. You can try out the [demo version](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/idadowndemo.htm).